# How to write data into Excel file?

Tags: c#, selenium, oledb

I  need to write function to write data into Excel file.
I've written function like:

```
public static void WriteToExcel(string fullFileName)
{
    OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;
    objConnection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION_STRING.Replace("<FILENAME>", fullFileName));
    objConnection.Open();
    OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update [global_nav$] SET A15 = 'DesiredNumber'", objConnection);
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Exactly how does this "not work". Also, how does this relate to selenium?

Comment: What's the output?  Are you getting error messages?  In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: So it does not write into excel file. Selenium I added because I use it in my automation script.

Comment: Error:No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library before.

I certainly found it easier than trying to use OLE.
Here's how to set the value of a cell:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "something";
```

Comment: Could you please give me some program example? Thanks

Comment: Here's an example where someone is using it to create a new spreadsheet containing a report: http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html

Comment: @ktarik, if you're happy with this answer, can you please tick it as accepted?